# What is a Dictionary of Arrays in OOP?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, data-structures, naming-conventions

In the context of OOP, what is the name (or class name) of a data structure composed of a Dictionary of Arrays? 
(a Dictionary where each key is mapped to a collection of values)

In the case you cannot find a class representing this data structure, what would be a proper name for this object?

I came from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structure but the most similar I've found is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap which it seems to me that is wrong because the article talks about cardinality and I don't care about that.

Comment: "A mess". Just use a multimap, which if you need it, allows you to access the vectors for each key.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is usually just called a Dictionary of Arrays. ;) Usually you don't need a special data structure, you just have a dictionary that has references to Arrays as values.